# How to add a new line at the beginning of constructor body in Eclipse formatter?

Tags: java, eclipse, formatter

I'm using eclipse Neon, but this could be present in previous versions too.

The formatter allows to add a blank line at the beginning of a method body, but it does not allow to do the same for constructors. This snippet is taken directly from the preview code of the formatter editor:

```
public Example(LinkedList list) {
    fList = list;
    counter = 0;
}

public void push(Pair p) {

    fList.add(p);
    ++counter;
}
```

I want the constructor to look the same as the method. I could not find a way to do that in the formatter settings.

(This is not a question about the right way to format code - these are closed as opinion based. This is a question about configuring a tool in an IDE. Please keep the discussion relevant.)

Comment: I have to ask... why do you want to add a blank line at the start of any method? I have never seen this done (deliberately)

Comment: @Bohemian Doesn't matter really. That's how I have read all the code in my life and I see it used everywhere. Really surprised you've *never* seen it. Eclipse even has it as default.

Comment: No. The eclipse default is no blank line: `Java > Code Style > Formatter > Blank Lines > At beginning of method body == 0`. Never seen anyone put blank lines in there.

Comment: Maybe it's there so you can till method bodies apart from constructor bodies quickly. Still I have never seen anyone consistently putting empty lines at the start of method bodies.

Comment: @Bohemian Not for me, it's 1. In any case, I asked a technical question, not an opinion based one and the comment section is quickly turning into that. Can you please move the comments to the chat as is usually done with irrelevant and long discussions?